# Emmet-Atom custom snippet for CSS module

Tags: css, reactjs, code-snippets, atom-editor, emmet

I'm using CSS modules with ReactJs (jsx). Is there a way to create a custom snippet within Emmet or Atom to use CSS modules instead of regular classes?

Example, currently Emmet works as follows:
`.title` expands to `<div className="title"></div>`

I want to be able to create a snippet similar to:
`.styles-title` expands to `<div className={styles.title}></div>`

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I'm looking to solve the same thing myself. I'll report back here if I find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually turned out to be rather tricky. Emmet and the Atom extension both allow for customization, but a security policy in Atom does [not allow loading custom filters from outside the extension](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/205).

With some nudging in the right direction (see the GitHub issue linked above) I was able to write [my own Atom extension that does this](https://atom.io/packages/emmet-jsx-css-modules).